# why image is not center in canvas using in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

could you please tell me why my image is not in centered I used this method

```
function drawImage() {
                    clear();
                    element.save();
                    element.scale(currentScale, currentScale);
                    element.rotate(currentAngle * Math.PI / 180);
                    element.drawImage(image, canvas.width/2-image.width/2, canvas.height/2-image.height/2);
                    element.restore();
                }
```

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/Tvika6ygEBGmR9OMLSaT?p=preview

expected output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

first you use scale so you must do somthing like

```
image.width * currentScale
```

then you must use

`Math.abs()` for positive value

or check image width /2 is not greater than canvas width /2

your current values is -1578 -2129

for this line

```
 element.drawImage(image, canvas.width/2-image.width/2, canvas.height/2-image.height/2);
```

Comment: pls share the plunker

Comment: i told you where, you have problem , you must check your values